# SDL2: Render textures YUV and RGB

Tags: rendering, sdl-2, pixelformat

Is it possible to render textures with different pixel format (YUV420 and RGB444) simultanuously? Here is a superposition of two textures of the same image (little picture has lost color):

[image]

Comment: It seems there was something wrong in my virtual machine. Today I'm back to the experiment after restart VM (usually I save state only) and found it working fine. No significant changes was made in my code. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works fine. Probably an incorrect operation of the VM may have occurred.